# how can i remove particular word in a table cell using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to remove 'def' from bellow table cells using Jquery.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>abc def</td>
        <td>xyz def</td>
        <td>lmn def</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>def</td>
        <td>abc def</td>
        <td>xyz def</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**
You can do this:

```
$("td:contains(def)").each(function(){
  var newText = $(this).text().replace(/def/g, "");
  $(this).text(newText);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this wonder full reply. could you please explain why we need to add 'g' after /def/

Comment: You're welcom. The `g` modifier is used to replace all 'def' appereances (in case there is more than once), without `g` it would only replace the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and pass a function to the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
$("td:contains(def)").text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.replace("def", "");
});
```

Comment: I Have one more doubt. You can see individual string 'def' in second row first cell. Without deleting all def string how can i delete that individual def string

Comment: @Hearaman, then you'd have to use `fiter()` to match the `<td>` elements whose `text()` is equal to `"def"`.